# Codeigniter inserir registro no banco

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Olá, trabalho com o Codeigniter 3.

Tenho uma dúvida.

Supomos a model abaixo:

```
class Peca_model extends CI_Model 
{
public $Id;
public $Data_registro;
public $Ativo;
public $Nome;

public function set_peca()
{
    if(empty($this->Id))
        return $this->db->insert('Peca', $this);
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('Id', $this->Id);
        return $this->db->update('Peca', $this);
    }
}
}
```

Bem, assim é a maneira como eu insiro um registro no banco de dados. Isso aí em cima funciona, testei e está ok.

Agora segue abaixo a mesma model, com uma pequena modificação: um atributo a mais adicionado a ela.

```
class Peca_model extends CI_Model 
{
public $Id;
public $Data_registro;
public $Ativo;
public $Nome;
public $Transacoes;    

public function set_peca()
{
    if(empty($this->Id))
        return $this->db->insert('Peca', $this);
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('Id', $this->Id);
        return $this->db->update('Peca', $this);
    }
}
}
```

OBS.: A MINHA TABELA **PEÇA** NO BANCO DE DADOS NÃO POSSUI ESSE ATRIBUTO **TRANSACOES**.

Bem, se eu tentar fazer um insert de algum registro no banco, o seguinte erro ocorre:

Unknown column 'Transacoes' in 'field list'

Claro, já é de se esperar por esse erro.

Agora que meu problema está explicado eu gostaria de saber como faço (se é que é possível no codeigniter) informar de alguma forma que o atributo Transacoes não faz parte do registro a ser inserido. Eu gostaria de usar esse atributo apenas como um atributo para ser preenchido por um objeto retornado por outro model (o objeto retornado por outro model seria de acordo com o Peca_id).

O exemplo é bem bobo, mas a ideia é essa.

Alguém pode me dizer se há uma forma de resolver isso? Como ignorar um atributo da classe ao fazer insert ou update que seja.

Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

descobri como fazer isso. É muito simples. Decidi compartilhar com vocês, pois talvez tenha mais pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

A classe abaixo como mencionei anteriormente, ao tentar fazer o insert ou update de algum registro dava erro, pois como eu disse, $Transacoes não é um campo na minha tabela no banco de dados e sim é um objeto relacionado. Ou seja, pra cada peça eu posso ter uma lista de transações. Segue abaixo a classe com o problema resolvido.

```
class Peca_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public $Id;
    public $Data_registro;
    public $Ativo;
    public $Nome;
    public $Transacoes;    

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->model('Transacao_model');
        $this->Trasacoes= $this->Transacao_model;
    }
    public function set_peca()
    {
        if(empty($this->Id))
            return $this->db->insert('Peca', $this);
        else
        {
            $this->db->where('Id', $this->Id);
            return $this->db->update('Peca', $this);
        }
    }
}
```

Notem que agora há um construtor responsável por carregar uma instância do objeto relacionado para dentro do atributo $Transacoes. Ao fazer isso, o insert/update irá ignorar o atributo $transacoes.

Na classe acima o problema foi resolvido, agora a utilidade para isso seria se tivéssemos um método que retornasse uma peça que conteria também sua lista de transações. Fazendo isso deixamos tudo em um objeto só, em vez que ficar fazendo várias chamadas de métodos de model no controller para recuperar registros relacionados. Ou seja, quando é objeto que tem algum relacionamento com outro, já retorna os dois numa única chamada no model.

Obrigado a todos.